# drupal 7: ajax functionalty does not work when displaying the node form in another page or in block?

Tags: nodes, forms, ajax

**I have created a content type. I then alter the form of that content type to display extra button to save node using ajax**:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'MyModuleName_node_add_callback',
    'wrapper' => $form_state['node']->type . '-node-form',
    'name' => 'submit1',
  ),
  '#value' => t('Submit Me'),
);
```

I then display the form for creating this content type in another page using this code

```
function MYMODULENAME_node_form($type){
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add($type); 
  return $form;
}
```

Now, the problem is that when i click on the button that i have created it shows me error this msg:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>
> HTTP Result Code: 500
>
> Debugging information follows. Path: /path/system/ajax StatusText: Internal Server Error
>
> ResponseText:

Can you please help me fixing this problem??

Thanks in advance
Mojo